# Users cannot subscribe to pushpad

Tags: node.js, pushpad

I am trying to use: pushpad
But when the user clicks on the "push notifications" link
It opens: `https://pushpad.xyz/projects/3247/subscription/edit?uid=1&uid_signature=b537f55122d37236296c221342b552de26478d36`

And the page says:

> The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the
>   address or the page may have moved.

Answer (score 0):

If the project ID is correct, then it's because you're using the link for Pushpad Express, but your project and sender are configured to use Pushpad Pro. You can check that by going to the sender settings.

You need to do one of the following:

- keep your project and sender and use Pushpad Pro ([Getting started](https://pushpad.xyz/docs/pushpad_pro_getting_started)); OR...
- delete your project and sender (to avoid further confusion); then create a new sender with Pushpad Express (enter a Pushpad subdomain as the domain, like `my-project.pushpad.xyz`) and create a new project associated to it; finally you can use the link for Pushpad Express

Comment: 1. I am pretty sure that I used Express and not Pro.
2. I can't find the "sender settings" (there is no "settings" there).
3. It is not clear what is the diffrence between Express and Pro.
What can I do in Pro that I cannot do in Express, and what does it costs me to do it?

Comment: 1,2. Click "Senders" in the top navigation, click on you sender; you can find the name of the product (Express / Pro) that you are using there. If there are no senders listed there or if your sender uses Express, then create a new sender for Pro and use that. 3. Basically Express gives you a hosted page on Pushpad to collect subscriptions ([more](https://pushpad.xyz/docs)); if you are developing a web app I suggest that you use Pushpad Pro, so that you can use the Javascript SDK on your own domain. Pricing for Pro and Express is exactly the same.